# Looping through a pandas df: ValueError: 0 is not in range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem wit a loop over a data frame.
The loop raises a KeyError in the 3rd if statement and says:
ValueError: 0 is not in range

If I just print(song_attributes['duration_ms'] I get an element with index 0.

```
for i in song_attributes.index:

        if song_attributes['loudness'][i] > 0:
            song_attributes['loudness'][i] = (song_attributes['loudness'][i]) * -1

        if song_attributes['mode'][i] != 1 or song_attributes['mode'][i] != 0 :
            song_attributes.drop(i,inplace=True)

        if song_attributes['duration_ms'][i] <= 1000:
            song_attributes['duration_ms'][i] = round(song_attributes['duration_ms'][i].mean(),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because index values ​​change(decrease) after drop operation. In your example, because row 0 has been removed, it cannot find row 0 in the **duration_ms** condition and returns an error. You can use drop condition at the end.

```
for i in song_attributes.index:
    print(i)
    if song_attributes['loudness'][i] > 0:
        song_attributes['loudness'][i] = (song_attributes['loudness'][i]) * -1
    
    if song_attributes['duration_ms'][i] <= 1000:
        song_attributes['duration_ms'][i] = round(song_attributes['duration_ms'][i].mean(),0)

    if song_attributes['mode'][i] == 1 or song_attributes['mode'][i] == 0 :
        song_attributes.drop(i,inplace=True)
```

or you can use **np.where()** without loop:

```
import numpy as np

song_attributes['loudness']=np.where(song_attributes['loudness'] > 0,(song_attributes['loudness']) * -1,song_attributes['loudness'])
song_attributes['duration_ms']=np.where(song_attributes['duration_ms'] <= 1000 , round(song_attributes['duration_ms'].mean(),0),song_attributes['duration_ms'])


song_attributes['check']=(song_attributes['mode'] != 1) | (song_attributes['mode'] != 0)
song_attributes=song_attributes[song_attributes['check']==False].drop(['check'],axis=1)
```